# Условия для выпадающего списка

Tags: php

Имеется выпадающий список:

```
$form.="<TD >".(($row['ore']==1)?("Медноцинковая"):("Медная"))."</TD>";
```

Как сделать условие, чтобы если

- `$row['ore']==1`, то выпадает ("Медноцинковая"),
- `$row['ore']==2`, то выпадает ("Медная"),
- `$row['ore']==3`, то выпадает ("Золотосодержащая")

Comment: `$cases = ['',"Медноцинковая","Медная",.. ]; $form.="".$cases[$row['ore']]."";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Допустим, тут значение 1
$row['ore'] = 1;

$array = ["Медноцинковая", "Медная", "Золотосодержащая"];

echo $array[--$row['ore']] ?? null;//Медноцинковая
```

> А в контексте вашего кода будет так:

```
$array = ["Медноцинковая", "Медная", "Золотосодержащая"];

$form .= "<TD >". ($array[--$row['ore']] ?? '') ."</TD>";
```

Comment: благодарю, всё получилось